# Adjusting CommandTimeout in Dapper.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, dapper

I'm trying to run SQL backups through a stored procedure through Dapper (the rest of my app uses Dapper so I'd prefer to keep this portion running through it as well). It works just fine until the CommandTimeout kicks in.

```
using (var c = SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    c.Open();
    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    // fill out p

    c.Execute("xp_backup_database", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

The only CommandTimeout setting I know of is in SqlCommand. Is there a way to set this via Dapper?

Comment: For whatever reason, I can't answer my own question right now. But it seems just adding the named argument "commandTimeout: 0" to c.Execute() took care of this.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple versions of the Execute function. One (or more) of them contains the commandTimeout parameters:

```
public static int Execute(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, 
                dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, 
                            int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
```

Taken from [SqlMapper.cs](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L440)

Comment: I had the same problem, but with Query method, however the solution worked for it too, as it has a commandTimeout parameter too.

Comment: From my experience the commandTimeout property is not used when using async await as stated in the msdn documentation (https://goo.gl/2NVlXL). Bit of a stinger hope it helps.

Comment: @DrSchizo why would it not be used, there's no reason for Async Await to avoid the Time out

Comment: @DrSchizo The docs say its not used with asynchronous methods like BeginExecuteReader, not async/await.  I assume this is because if you use BeginExecuteReader, it is assumed you will use your own timeout logic.

Comment: Is it possible to set this timeout for all queries? I tried with the `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout Property` but it says that it's read only. I would need it for some custom migration programs. It's tedious to type it with every statement.

Comment: @jedatkinports SqlMapper.Settings.CommandTimeout I believe is what you are after.

Comment: @Tadej The `ConnectionTimeout` property is not a global timeout setting for all connections but rather the amount of time the system will wait for a connection to open. You can only set it in the connection string because once the connection is open it is too late, hence it is a readonly property. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout

Comment: If yoiu do want a global setting see the answer by Mozart below https://stackoverflow.com/a/62655346/470014

Answer (score 77):

Example from original question with accepted answer added, in case anyone wants it. (Timeout is set to 60 seconds):

```
using (var c = SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    c.Open();
    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    // fill out p

    c.Execute("xp_backup_database", p, commandTimeout: 60, 
                                       commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Answer (score 52):

There is no need to set command timeout for all queries/Db Calls. You can set it globally like below.

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.Settings.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

You can initialize this static property on the application load or in the database class constructor.

This helps in removing duplication, and in case you decide to change it later, you change it once in one place.

Comment: where do we put this command?

Comment: @JohnathanLi It depends on the type of your application. but usually somewhere in the initialization code of you app.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve my problem using connection.Query
setting the timeout directly

```
int timeOutInSeconds = 60;
.
.
.
result = conn.Query<list>(stringQuery, new {parameters, ..}, null, true, timeOutInSeconds).ToList();
```