# Why there is a difference in output/performance while executing SQL query in SSMS and in code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, database-performance

I started to use dapper.net a while ago for performance reasons and that I really like the named parameters feature compared to just run `ExecuteQuery` in LINQ To SQL.

It works great for most queries but I get some really weird timeouts from time to time. The strangest thing is that this timeout only happens when the SQL is executed via dapper. If I take the executed query copied from the profiler and just run it in Management Studio its fast and works perfect. And it's not just a temporary issues. The query consistently timeout via dapper and consistently works fine in Management Studio.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT Item.Name,dbo.PlatformTextAndUrlName(Item.ItemId) As PlatformString,dbo.MetaString(Item.ItemId) As MetaTagString, Item.StartPageRank,Item.ItemRecentViewCount
                        NAME_SRCH.RANK as NameRank,
                        DESC_SRCH.RANK As DescRank, 
                        ALIAS_SRCH.RANK as AliasRank, 
                        Item.itemrecentviewcount,
                        (COALESCE(ALIAS_SRCH.RANK, 0)) + (COALESCE(NAME_SRCH.RANK, 0)) + (COALESCE(DESC_SRCH.RANK, 0) / 20) + Item.itemrecentviewcount / 4 + ((CASE WHEN altrank > 60 THEN 60 ELSE altrank END) * 4) As SuperRank
                        FROM dbo.Item
                        INNER JOIN dbo.License on Item.LicenseId = License.LicenseId
                        
                        LEFT JOIN dbo.Icon on Item.ItemId = Icon.ItemId
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Item, name, @SearchString) NAME_SRCH ON
                        Item.ItemId = NAME_SRCH.[KEY] 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Item, namealiases, @SearchString) ALIAS_SRCH ON
                        Item.ItemId = ALIAS_SRCH.[KEY] 
                        INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Item, *, @SearchString) DESC_SRCH ON
                        Item.ItemId = DESC_SRCH.[KEY]
                        ORDER BY SuperRank DESC OFFSET @Skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @Count ROWS ONLY',N'@Count int,@SearchString nvarchar(4000),@Skip int',@Count=12,@SearchString=N'box,com',@Skip=0
```

That is the query that i copy pasted from SQL Profiler. I execute it like this in my code.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    var items = connection.Query<MainItemForList>(query, new { SearchString = searchString, PlatformId = platformId, _LicenseFilter = licenseFilter, Skip = skip, Count = count }, buffered: false);
    return items.ToList();
}
```

I have no idea where to start from. I suppose there must be something that is going on with dapper since it works fine when I just execute the code.

As you can see in this screenshot. This is the same query executed via code first and then via Management Studio.

[image: Screen shot]

I can also add that this only (I think) happens when I have two or more word or when I have a `stop` char in the search string. So it may have something to do with the full text search but I cant figure out how to debug it since it works perfectly from Management Studio.

To make matters even worse, it works fine on my localhost with a almost identical database both from code and from Management Studio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dapper is nothing more than a utility wrapper over ado.net; it does not change how ado.net operates. It sounds to me that the problem here is "works in ssms, fails in ado.net". This is not unique: it is pretty common to find this occasionally. Likely candidates:

- "set" option: these have different defaults in ado.net - and can impact performance especially if you have things like calculated+persisted+indexed columns - if the "set" options aren't compatible it can decide it can't use the stored value, hence not the index - and instead table-scan and recompute. There are other similar scenarios.
- system load / transaction isolation-level / blocking; running something in ssms does not reproduce the entire system load at that moment in time
- cached query plans: sometimes a duff plan gets cached and used; running from ssms will usually force a new plan - which will naturally be tuned for the parameters you are using in your test. Update all your index stats etc, and consider adding the "optimise for" query hint

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but it was kind of hard to test. Anyway i think it had to do with the cached query plans. I got the time out locally now and restarted the server and then it worked. I tried adding a "OPTIMIZE FOR" thingy now. Hopefully that will help. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: How do you correctly manage the "set" option for adhoc queries passed into Dapper/SqlCommand.ExecuteReader?

Comment: @Terry "set" options are at the connection level - so you'd need to open the connection, then (for example) `connection.Execute("SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON");`, then (the rest of your code); you can also prefix individual commands with `SET` instructions. Note, however, that not all `SET` options are reset by `sp_reset_connection` (which is executed automatically when connections are resued) - for example (and in particular) `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL {blah};` persists even between connection resets, which can be... fun

Comment: Thanks.  And the process to debug why ADO.NET times out vs SSMS, simply start toggling SET options and see which happens to affect it?

Comment: I added OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of the SQL statemet that I sent to the DB and that solved it for me [based on point 3 above]

Comment: @akraines `recompile` is a terrible hint, that should almost never be used; `for unknown` is probably the one you want

Answer (score 8):

In ADO is the default value for CommandTimeout 30 Seconds, in Management Studio infinity. Adjust the command timeout for calling Query<>, see below.

```
var param = new { SearchString = searchString, PlatformId = platformId, _LicenseFilter = licenseFilter, Skip = skip, Count = count };
var queryTimeoutInSeconds = 120;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    var items = connection.Query<MainItemForList>(query, param, commandTimeout: queryTimeoutInSeconds, buffered: false);
    return items.ToList();
}
```

See also 
[SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CommandTimeout(v=VS.110).aspx)

Comment: Link in English: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandTimeout

Answer (score 3):

For Dapper , default timeout is 30 seconds But we can increase the timeout in this way. Here we are incresing the timeout 240 seconds (4 minutes).

```
    public DataTable GetReport(bool isDepot, string fetchById)
    {
        int? queryTimeoutInSeconds = 240;
        using (IDbConnection _connection = DapperConnection)
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@IsDepot", isDepot);
            parameters.Add("@FetchById", fetchById);
            var res = this.ExecuteSP<dynamic>(SPNames.SSP_GetSEPReport, parameters, queryTimeoutInSeconds);
            return ToDataTable(res);
        }
    }
```

In the repository layer , we can call our custom ExecuteSP method for the Stored Procedures with additional parameters "queryTimeoutInSeconds".

And below is the "ExecuteSP" method for dapper:-

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> ExecuteSP<TEntity>(string spName, object parameters = null, int? parameterForTimeout = null)
    {
        using (IDbConnection _connection = DapperConnection)
        {
            _connection.Open();
            return _connection.Query<TEntity>(spName, parameters, commandTimeout: parameterForTimeout, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be a matter of setting the command timeout in Dapper.  Here's an example of how to adjust the command timeout in Dapper:
[Setting Command Timeout in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794858/adjusting-commandtimeout-in-dapper-net)

Answer (score 0):

Dapper defaults to make the parameter VARCHAR(4000). On a large table this causes a very slow read, as if it's not using the indexes.

Change this:

`var result = await _connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Record>(sql, new { recordId });`

to this:

`var result = await _connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Record>(sql, new { recordId = new DbString { Value = recordId, Length = 15 }});`

(Or if you're confident that SQL injection isn't possible then put your parameter directly in the SQL string).

References:

[SQL Server Hidden “Load Evil” (Performance Issue)With Dapper](https://jithilmt.medium.com/sql-server-hidden-load-evil-performance-issue-with-dapper-465a08f922f6)

[Dapper.NET: The varchar(4000) default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089420/dapper-net-the-varchar4000-default)