# Dapper.NET: The varchar(4000) default

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, dapper

I am using Dapper.NET and when i execute the next code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            con.Execute(@" insert Clients(name) values(@Name)", new {Name = "John"});
            con.Close();
        }
```

The query that it executes is the next one:

```
(@Name nvarchar(4000)) insert Clients(name) values(@Name)
```

And my question is: **why is Dapper translating a string to a nvarchar(4000)?** I mean... on the database, the *name* field is a *nvarchar(50)*...

Does anybody face this bug? How do you fix it? Have you found another bug like this?

Comment: I'd say (but it's pure conjecture) it's because Dapper doesn't know anything about your table structure, and in .NET `string` is UTF-16 (so non ANSI-string) that's potentially without size limit other than memory. That translates to `nvarchar` type with maximum available length. I'd say it's not a bug, but you have to do validation yourself or catch data integrity violation exceptions on `INSERT`.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a bug. Dapper has to pick a SQL data-type for a string parameter, without looking at the database structure (not to mention parsing your query and determining that you're inserting the parameter into a particular column).

Imagine if you were doing this:

```
insert Clients(name) values(@Name + 'abc')
```

Should Dapper have to figure out that @Name can be up to 47 characters?

You can be more specific about the size of your parameter if you like:

```
con.Execute(@" insert Clients(name) values(@Name)", 
    new { Name = new DbString { Value = "John", Length = 50 }});
```

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how can i do for having this more readable? Because if there is an insert with a lot of fields (string fields) it would be very ugly... And is there something like this with another type? Thanks