# .NET v2 IIS timeout after 30 seconds (not always)

Tags: sql-server, iis, .net-core, windows-server

First of all I would like to point out that this is, in my eyes, not a duplicate question, because the timeout as described in the title happens 8/10 times. So not always.

We have a .NET application with Dapper, but all of a sudden the application stops the request after 30 seconds. We have had this issue before and fixed it by updating all `limit` options in IIS and adding `executionTimeout="00:30:00"` to the `web.conf` file of IIS. (In the aspNet section).

The above fixed the issue for one of our applications, including this one. But all of a sudden this problem seems to be back.

The strange thing is that **it doesn't always happen**. Sometimes the application continues with the request for 40, 50 or more seconds. But **8/10 times** it stops after exactly 30 seconds.

We also have a `executionTimeout` set in the code where we call the query. This is set on 1800 seconds.

In our eyes this must be a IIS issue or perhaps even a database issue (**MSSQL**)? But we are unsure what to do next, because it doesn't always happen. If it was a IIS problem, wouldn't it always happen even if we test it a thousand times?

If someone could help us with this problem we would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT code snippets:

C#:

```cs
var result = await _connection.QueryAsync<Sample>(sql, commandTimeout: 1800);
```

web.config:

```
<aspNetCore ... executionTimeout="00:30:00" ... />
```

Comment: There are too many variables here to be certain.  I would approach this by attempting to make the process faster. Your customers will appreciate it and you won't have to worry about timeouts.  That said... if you run the query directly in SQL Server Management Studio, how long does it take to execute?

Comment: `executionTimeout` controls the timeout of the [HTTP Runtime in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/wmi-provider/httpruntimesection-class). You're probably looking for the [SqlCommand's CommandTimeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout), which defaults to 30 seconds.

Comment: @GeorgeMastros unfortunately the query is REALLY complex and the database is HUGE. So this results in slow times, but the customer is OK with that. The query takes a while to execute directly in management studio (only on the production database). The test database takes less than one second. (less data).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning We use Dapper and there it is called executionTimeout. It is set on 1800 seconds in code where the query is running.

Comment: What happens if you specify the timeout on all three, the [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandTimeout), the [connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and the [context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_DataContext_CommandTimeout)?

Comment: Do you have log files that tell you where you were in your code when the timeout occurred?   Any code samples?

Comment: interesting one, if you've checked all the above timeouts, (command etc), what about web limits? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/webLimits  other things to look at, check the iis logs, windows event viewer (application section), look at app pool recycling - a recycle can be triggered by too much memory being used -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/application-pools-recycle-when-memory-limits-are-exceeded

Comment: @KittyCat, I know nothing about Dapper but an internet search suggests one should set `commandTimeout`, not `executionTimeout`, to control SQL command execution behavior. Add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @KittyCat - You should try to increase the command timeout while calling the execute method of the dapper.net. Have a look https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/8794858/adjusting-commandtimeout-in-dapper-net-

Comment: What exactly do you mean with context? The command timeout and connection timeout are both set though. @GSerg

Comment: @ChristopherPainter No we have no log files because it only happens in production and that environment is strictly private unfortunately (for us).

Comment: @JosephHopkins we did set all web limits in IIS. Are there any hidden limits?

Comment: @DanGuzman We already do that. I probably explained it wrongly!

Comment: @MukeshArora We already do this. Read the comments for more information.

Comment: @KittyCat `What exactly do you mean with context?` - the data access context, if you are using any, such as an EF context or a Linq2Sql context.

Comment: @GSerg We do not use any of these.

Comment: @KittyCat re: hidden limits, not that I know of, if you recycle your app pool on purpose during the query do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to increase the **CommandTimeout** while calling the **Execute** method of the dapper.net.

*Refer to these URLs for more details*

[dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/8794858/](https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/8794858/adjusting-commandtimeout-in-dapper-net-)

[adjusting-commandtimeout-in-dapper-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794858/adjusting-commandtimeout-in-dapper-net)

Answer (score 0):

"requestTimeout" throw an error when there is no possibility to begin the query due to a lock over one resource that is uncompatible with the lock you need to put to begin the exexcution of the query.

So if the 30 seconds have been passed, the query is running, but the execution time can be greater that 30 seconds...

Comment: One answer wich would be much appreciated is to give us the ISOLATION LEVEL used for the queries, and espcially if you have activate the SNAPSHOT isolation level that will avoid most of the "requestTimout".

Comment: This is correct. We see the query running in the activity monitor of MSSQL. But the request still stops after 30 seconds 8/10 times.

Comment: The activity monitor is not quite accurate to show all the problems. Can you execute this query ?

Comment: SELECT session_id, blocking_session_id, q.text
FROM   sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS q
WHERE  session_id > 50
  AND  database_id > 5
  AND session_id <> @@SPID 
  AND blocking_session_id > 0;

Comment: this returns nothing unfortunately.