# C# Dapper stored proc error - "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a list of stored procedures using the below code.

The Dot Net 6.0/Dapper/MySQL code is throwing the following exception

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

```
foreach (string sProc SpList)
{

    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
         var result = await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync(sProc , null, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

Some of the stored procs was taking more than 10 minutes to complete on the work bench. This is a backend job and I just want to execute list of stored procedures successfully.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjusting CommandTimeout in Dapper.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794858/adjusting-commandtimeout-in-dapper-net)

Comment: It looks like a `connection.Open()` is missing.